# slick carousel is not working in *ngFor directive in angular2

Tags: angular, async-await, carousel, slick.js

Slick carousel is working with static data. But if i repeat the items using *ngFor, but it is not working.  I have tried with all life cycle hooks(AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked), Please help.

```js
import {
  Component, OnInit
}
from '@angular/core';
declare
let jQuery: any;
import 'slick-carousel';

@
Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.less']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    jQuery(".slider").slick({        
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      slidesToShow: 6         
    })
  }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div *ngFor="let image of images">
    <img src={{image.name}} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "is not working"? Any errors?

Comment: slider is not getting applied. If i gives 10 images at once, all the images are getting displayed. I need to display 6 images, then after sliing i need to show remaining images

Answer (score 3):

I used setTimeout()

```
  setTimeout( ()=>{
          this.initCarousel();
          this.showProduct = true;
        }, 1000);
```

where the initCarousel() contains

```
 $(".slider").slick({

  // normal options...
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
  arrows: true,
  autoplay: true,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 5,
  // the magic
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1200,
      settings: {
          arrows: true,
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 4
      }
  },
    {

      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        infinite: true
      }

    }, {

      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        dots: true
      }

    }, {

      breakpoint: 300,
      settings: "unslick" // destroys slick

    }]
});
```

and it worked fine for me.
Full code:

```
this.api.getAllProducts()
  .pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const did = a.payload.doc.id;
    return {did, ...data};
  })))
    .subscribe(res =>{
      this.products = res;
      if(this.products.length > 0)
        setTimeout( ()=>{
          this.initCarousel();
          this.showProduct = true;
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Using this timeout worked for me. But there is a better way to handle this situation with unslick() function. If anyone know that method please update.